# Unity3d - eulerAngles (local and global) totally different than what's in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, euler-angles

In the inspector for a gameObject I'm using the starting rotation is "-90", but when I run `print(transform.eulerAngles.x)` I get 270 (ditto for `transform.localEulerAngles.x`).

If I tilt the `gameObject` downward, the inspector X value gets bigger (say, to -85) as it should. The printed `transform.eulerAngles.x` also gets bigger, say to 274.

Here's where things get weird:

If I tilt the `gameObject` upward the inspector x coordinate gets smaller (ex, to -95), as it should, BUT the printed `eulerAngle.x` value gets BIGGER (here to 274). So if I rotate the object up or down from the `eulerAngle.x` being 270, the x value increases regardless.

I'm definitely doing something wrong here, but after a lot of troubleshooting I still can't figure out what. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the gameobject a child of another gameobject?

Comment: Nope, it is not. :/

Comment: it's explained over and over and over in the unity documentation.  **SIMPLY USE 'Rotate'**.  It's that simple.

Comment: Tried using 'Rotate' and afraid its not that simple... that doesnt work either...

Answer (score 3):

eulerAngles are a convoluted process in Unity3D. You should never increment/decrement or set the values in your inspector or via code. Should only use absolute values to read and set it.

Don't increment or decrement the values, as it will fail when the angle exceeds 360 degrees. Transform.Rotate is what you use instead.

Here is the sample code in the Unity3D documentation example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float yRotation = 5.0F;
    void Update() {
        yRotation += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(10, yRotation, 0);
    }
    void Example() {
        print(transform.eulerAngles.x);
        print(transform.eulerAngles.y);
        print(transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
}
```

This is taken directly from the documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html

Also Transform.Rotate documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

The inspector will almost always give you a funky value vs when you log it. The only consistency you will get is print(transform.rotation). This should retain similar values across inspector and code.

Comment: I've read the documentation. I'm not incrementing or decrementing the values, just reading them. EDIT: Also, the part about print(transform.rotation) is not true. transform is a quaternion, so printing it will only give you the x,y,z,w quaternion values, not the eulerAngles.

Comment: try logging transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x.  Curious to see the output.

Comment: Output is the same for transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x and transform.eulerAngles.x, ditto for localEulerAngles.x

Comment: i wonder if the printed eulerAngle.x value is using a different space vs the inspector one.

Comment: I have an interesting thing to try. Maybe keep your transform's eulerangle in a Vector3 variable with public scope so you can see it in inspector. Output the var in Update() to keep track of it, and view it in inspector to see if they correlate.

Comment: How can I test this? The really weird thing to me is that the eulerAngle.x value never goes below 270, rotating it downward increases its value the same as rotating it upward, when the value in the inspector behaves as expected...

Comment: Oops, missed the second post. When I save the position to a public Vector3 variable, the rotations match what was printed not what was in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

For each value in `transform.eulerAngles` or `transform.localEulerAngles` if it has a parent:

```
if (value > 270)
    value -= 360;
```